# extracting CDATA with KissXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, kissxml

is there a way I can access the CDATA Value in a xml string using KissXML?

My obj-c code:

```
for(DDXMLElement* itemElement in xmlItems)
{
 //get CDATA
}
```

String looks like this:

```
<item>
<title></title>
<link></link>
<description><![CDATA[<a href="">Link</a>description<a href="">another link</a> task]]>   </description>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

CDATA should manifest in the DOM tree as text, so just iterate the children of the element node looking for nodes whose `-kind` property is `DDXMLTextKind`.

```
NSMutableString* content = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (DDXMLNode* child in [parent children])
{
    if ([child kind] == DDXMLTextKind)
    {
        [content append: [child stringValue]];
    }
}
```

might do it, I haven't compiled or tested the above, but you can.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it. Can you give me a code example?